What are the correct expressions in Sports?
I'm wondering whether these are correct usage of expressions in sports:

I played football with my team last weekend.
I had a football match with my team yesterday. We won.
This weekend, I'm playing a basketball match with my team.
I went to a swimming competition or I'm participating in a swimming competition.
I'm playing gymnastics this Friday. I'm going to my gymnastics training this Friday.

Questions:

The emphasis "with my team" is it necessary? Or, if I only say,"I played football." does this already imply that I'm playing with my team?
I had a foootball match ... can we use "had" instead of "play" in this case?
I'm playing in a football match. Or, if I say simply, "I'm playing football." Does this always imply that it's a match? What about a random game with friends? Also,do we use in ?
I'm going to a swimming competition - does this mean I'm just watching a swimming competition? If I'm the one competing, do I have to use "participate" instead?
Can we use "play" for gymnastics?
If it's a gymnastics training, can we say,"I'm training for gymnastics."

Thank you so much for your kind help.

You certainly can't play football on your own. Realistically, you'll probably be playing "friendly" and/or formal competition games / matches with "your" team/club, so it's not necessary to explicitly mention them. To my mind, you'd only bring "my team" into it if you had some context-specific reason to be calling attention to them. Because you're about to start selling raffle tickets to raise club funds, or talking about the upcoming club xmas dinner, or something.

There are lots of different questions here.  I'm not sure which question to answer.  Could you try to cut it down to a single topic, please.

By the way, in American English, none of (American) football , soccer, basketball, baseball or hockey (whether ice or field) is played in matches; all those sports are played in games. For us, match is used when speaking of tennis, wrestling, and boxing, but not much else.

"I went to a swimming competition" (without context) implies that you were a spectator. You can use took part instead of the rather formal word participated.
